"in ähnlichem Rahmen" oder "im ähnlichen Rahmen"
Welche Wendung ist richtig?
"Wir treffen uns in ähnlichem Rahmen." oder
"Wir treffen uns im ähnlichen Rahmen."

Ich bin nicht sicher, ob nur ich das so sehe, deshalb frage ich lieber erstmal in einem Kommentar nach weiteren Meinungen. Für mich klingt "im ähnlichen Rahmen" nach einem tatsächlichen, physischen Rahmen (vielleicht eine Aufteilung einer großen Halle o. ä.), und "in ähnlichem Rahmen" nach einem Rahmen im übertragenen Sinn. Ist diese Unterscheidung halbwegs allgemeingültig?

@HenningKockerbeck Da man sich selten in einem Bilder- oder Fahrzeugrahmen trifft wird wohl fast immer etwas wie Kontext, Rahmen im metaphorischen Sinne gemeint sein, was aber für die Deklination keine Auswirkung hat.

Beide sind möglich und beide sind korrekt. Die Markierung des Dativs kann entweder am Artikel oder - sollte der fehlen - am Adjektiv erfolgen:

mit großem Eifer
mit dem großen Eifer

Das ist der Grund, warum in

im ähnlichen Rahmen

das "ähnlich" keine Dativendung erhält. "Im" ist nämlich schon der Träger derselben, als Zusammenziehung von "in dem". Hingegen ist in

in ähnlichem Rahmen

das "in" lediglich als Präposition verstanden und das "ähnlich", als Adjektiv, bekommt nun in Abwesenheit des Artikels die fällige Markierung.

Es wäre sinnvoll zu erwähnen, dass in den beiden Variationen einmal ein bestimmter und einmal ein unbestimmter Artikel verborgen ist.

In dem einen Fall ist der - bestimmte - Artikel nicht "verborgen", sondern in der Zusammenziehung enthalten. Das habe ich erwähnt. Im zweiten Fall ist kein Artikel, weder ein bestimmter noch ein unbestimmter, verborgen. Sonst wäre es nämlich "in einem ähnlichen Rahmen", weil dann der Artikel die Markierung trüge. zB enthält "in schöner Regelmäßigkeit" auch keinen Artikel, auch wenn man einen (und zwar sowohl einen bestimmten wie auch einen unbestimmten) einfügen könnte - aber den würde man dann einfügen, der ist nicht a priori schon da.


Wir treffen uns in ähnlichem Rahmen.

heißt

Wir treffen uns in einem ähnlichen Rahmen.



Wir treffen uns im ähnlichen Rahmen.

heißt

Wir treffen uns in dem ähnlichen Rahmen.


Da man diese Phrase meistens verwendet, ohne dass vorher ein konkreter Rahmen näher bestimmt wurde (das Wort "ähnlich" würde dazu auch nicht passen), klingt "im ähnlichen" seltsam.
